# The order of $\max_t x_t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

If $x_t=O(1)$ for each $t=1,...,T$, then what is the order of $\max_t x_t$ or $\sup_t x_t$? Is it $O(T)$, $O(\sqrt{T})$ or $O(1)$?

Comment: Can you share what you tried to do?

Comment: @zkutch I am trying to find the order of an expression that involves an object $\max_t x_t$. I know the order of $x_t$, but not sure if the max of $x_t$ is of the same order as $x_t$

Comment: As all $x_t$ are same order and $T$ is fixed, then $\sup$ becomes maximum.